# how can I get data from database in mysql in node js without using direct queries?

Tags: mysql, node.js

All of the examples I've found show how to use query by sql statement, as: 'connection.query("select * from my_table",...)', but I want to do it without sql statement, but with store procedure.
I found something about 'db-mysql' that supplies this option but I didn't success installing it.
I don't want to use sql statement in my code.
I want to select, update etc. by stored procedures in my mysqldatabase (like C#).
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://sequelizejs.com/ it is a node compatible orm which allows you to easily interface with sql without needing to use sql statements.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to understand the point but I decided to use sql statement, to call stored procedures and not to select, update directly.